# How to get bytecode of a Smart Contract using Remix editor?

Tags: solidity, remix

Why cant I get bytecode from Remix after compiling this contract code?

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21; // DRAFT 3

contract Ownable {
  address public owner;
  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


  function Ownable() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }


  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }



  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0) && newOwner != owner);
    emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }
}

///////////// SAFE MATH FUNCTIONS

library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}



contract Destructible is Ownable {

  function Destructible() public payable { }

  function destroy() onlyOwner public {
    selfdestruct(owner);
  }

  function destroyAndSend(address _recipient) onlyOwner public {
    selfdestruct(_recipient);
  }
}


contract UserTokensControl is Ownable {
  address companyReserve;
  address founderReserve;
  address contractReserve;
}


contract ERC223ReceivingContract {
  function tokenFallback(address _from, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public;
  event TokenFallback(address indexed from, uint256 value, bytes data);
}

contract ERC223 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value, bytes data) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value, bytes data);
}

contract ERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC223Interface is ERC223,ERC20 {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
}


contract BasicToken is ERC223Interface, UserTokensControl, ERC223ReceivingContract {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;


  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    require(_value > 0);

    uint256 codeLength;
    assembly {
      codeLength := extcodesize(_to)
    }

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    if(codeLength > 0) {
      //ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
      //receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
      emit TokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
    } else {
      emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
      return true;
    }
  }


  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    require(_value > 0);

    uint256 codeLength;
    bytes memory empty;
    assembly {
      codeLength := extcodesize(_to)
    }

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    if(codeLength > 0) {
      //ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
      //receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, empty);
      emit TokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, empty);
    } else {
      emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, empty);
      return true;
    }
  }


  function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }
}


contract StandardToken is BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;
}

contract TESTCONTRACT is StandardToken,Destructible {
  string public constant name = "TESTCONTRACT";
  uint public constant decimals = 18;
  string public constant symbol = "TESTSYMBOL1";

  function TESTCONTRACT() public {
    totalSupply=155000000 *(10**decimals);
    owner = msg.sender;
    companyReserve = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    founderReserve = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    contractReserve = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    balances[msg.sender] = 93000000 * (10**decimals);
    balances[companyReserve] = 31000000 * (10**decimals); 
    balances[founderReserve] = 26350000 * (10**decimals);
    balances[contractReserve] = 4650000 * (10**decimals);
  }

  function() public {
     revert();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access to the bytecode generated or the ABI, you need to click on the "Details" button on the right panel in Remix.

[image]

Once it's done, this will be displayed. It's just right there.

[image]

Comment: It's not showing up for me, only shows assembly code as 'null', hence why I'm asking on here.

Comment: It doesn't show you the bytecode for contracts with "unimplemented" functions. So you have to implement all the functions you have previously declared.

Comment: It seems you were correct about the unimplemented functions. I had 'transfer' and 'tokenFallback' declared up higher with the events for some reason. I'm getting a bunch of warnings on inline assembly now, but at least I'm able to start testing. My priority is to make sure I don't have a vulnerable contract because of something silly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

## To get the contract bytecode in Remix as of May 2022 as follow:

1. Open the "Solidity Compiler" from the icon
2. Go to the end of this sidebar as here
   [image]
3. Press on the Bytecode it will copy it
4. paste the code into an editor of your choice
5. Navigate to "object" in that pasted file
6. This is the bytecode of your smart contract
   [image]